# rsync: Only update owner/group and permissions?

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm in the process of duplicating a remote webserver and am using rsync to transfer the files:

```
rsync -rvz --ignore-existing -e ssh . root@(localip):/usr/files
```

It took about 12 hours to transfer 115GB of files only for me to find out I forgot the "-a" option. So now I have 115GB worth of files with the wrong owner/group and permissions.

Is there a way to use rsync so it only updates the owner/group/permissions without transferring the files again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, run the command again with the `-a` flag. `rsync` is smart enough and it will just change the owner/group.

You can see that if you use `-i` (itemize). It lists the changes done.

Comment: Just adding -a actually transfers the files as well. It displays `<f..tpog...` for each file.

Comment: That line means that just the time, permissions, owner and group are being updated. The file contents are not being transferred (you'd see a bunch of + signs if that were the case). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493525/what-does-f-mean-in-rsync-logs).

Comment: No, it actually transferred all files (which is confirmed by the `<`). Which (now I know what's causing it) makes sense because not only were the owner/group/permissions not set, time stamps were also incorrect so it always saw the destination files as "different". I had to add the `--size-only` parameter for it to not transfer the files (unless source and destination were of different size).

Comment: @Zippy1970 that's why then. If only the permissions had been wrong it would have worked. Good catch.